# angular-translate: urlLoader with additional query parameters

Tags: angularjs, angular-translate

Is there an option to call `angular-translate` module (made by Pascal Precht) with additional GET parameters, not only with `queryParameter` one when using `urlLoader`? Current implementation is as follow:

```
  $translateProvider.useLoader('$translateUrlLoader', {
    url: 'endpoint/translations',
    queryParameter: 'language'
  });
```

and then in paritucar controller as:

```
$translate.use('en');
```

What i need to do is to call it with more parameters, like:

```
  $translateProvider.useLoader('$translateUrlLoader', {
    url: 'endpoint/translations',
    config: {
      queryParameter: 'language',
      secondParam: 'screen',
      thirdParam: 'client'
    }
  });
```

and then in particular controller to be invoked it as:

```
$translate.use('en','login','pepsi');
```

As result I need to call my API endpoint like:

```
endpoint/translations?language=en&screen=login&client=pepsi
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

By the using the module called `angular-translate-loader-partial` module I think we can make this work (https://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/guide/12_asynchronous-loading)

Which is configured like this:

```
$translateProvider.useLoader('$translatePartialLoader', {
   urlTemplate: 'endpoint/translations/' + $rootScope.clientName + '/{part}/{lang}.json'      
});
```

And used in controller like:

```
 angular.module('pepsi').controller('sugerCtrl', function ($scope, $translatePartialLoader, $translate) {
  $translatePartialLoader.addPart('suger');
  $translate.refresh();
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for the reply, but i would like to avoid usage of `angular-translate-loader-static-files` i.e. static files as my endpoint returns dynamic JSON object based on these conditions.

Comment: Actually I'm only using `angular-translate-loader-partial`.

Comment: but can `$translatePartialLoader` works with endpoint URL, not with file(s)? this configuration will look for static `.json` file anyway, is that correct? as far i know, urlTemplate helps to define and use just different .json files.

Comment: I havn't quite tested this, but I think it should be able to load from an API with `urlTemplate`. After all its just an URL.

Comment: I think it is possible for cani's solution to work even with an endpoint that returns a dynamic JSON object. It all depends on how you actually handle the URL. You could rewrite it in the back end so that it invokes the endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

for me it works:

```
var serviceBase = 'http://localhost';
$translatePartialLoaderProvider.addPart('core');
$translateProvider.useLoader('$translatePartialLoader', {
    urlTemplate: serviceBase + '/api/translations?lang={lang}&module={part}'
});
$translateProvider.preferredLanguage("de");
```